# How to handle repeated input for a Keras layer?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, keras-layer

I have a Keras model which has two input layers.

1. a tweet of shape `(20,300)`.
2. five other tweets of shape `(5,20,300)`. however this input is same for all training examples.

In other word, for each training step, there will be a different tweet (first input) and the same five tweets (second input). My second input that has a shape of `(5,20,300)` is very big to be repeated `num_samples` times and then used as an input layer to Keras model.
I need a way to make the second input used inside the keras models but without repeated `num_samples` times.

Is there any way to handle this type of input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a tensor with that constant input:

```
fixed_tweets = keras.backend.constant(the_tweets_as_numpy)
```

Use a regular input and a `tensor` input:

```
input1 = Input((20,300))
input2 = Input(tensor=fixed_tweets)
```

Go have fun!!

You will probably need custom layers to handle the difference between the batch size of `input1` (any) and `input2` (5).